# Decrementing and incrementing a variable with an if condition produces unexpected result in C language

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I'm running this code from the command prompt.  The output of this code is 0 but I was expecting it to output 1. Can you explain how this code is actually compiled and runs?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x;
    x = 1;
    if (--x && ++x) {
        printf("Great");
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which language is this? Adjust your tags ...

Comment: `if(x-- && ++x)`.

Comment: short-circuiting --- https://ideone.com/tFV5wi

Answer (score 1):

--x decrements the value of x before using the value of the variable. So you start with x=1, then do an if clause

```
if (--x
```

which decrements x and then inspects the value. The value is now 0. You haven't put any other boolean test in there, in C `if (0)` equates to `false`. So it doesn't execute the second part of the conditional (which would incremenet x), it simply skips the 'if' clause and goes to printf and return 0.

If you change this to something like:

```
if (--x >= 0 && ++x >= 0)
```

Or:

```
if (x-- && x++)
```

Because x-- uses the variable before decrementing it, so the `if` will test x when its value is 1, before decrementing it. Then it'll do what you want.

Comment: consider replacing `>=` with `!=` because only zero is a false value.